# how to change color of a rectangle when I click on it for 3 seconds

Tags: qt, qml

I have a rectangle. I need to activate the rectangle (change its color to red) when I click on it for 3 seconds (meaning: kept pressed for 3 seconds).

I saw the properties onPressed, onReleased and onPressAndHold but how can I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Timer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html) for that purpose.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            Timer {
                id: timer
                repeat: false
                interval: 3000
                running: parent.pressed
                onTriggered: rect.state === "on" ? rect.state = "off" : rect.state = "on"
            }
        }

        states: [
            State {
                name: "on";
                PropertyChanges { target: rect; color: "green"; }
            },
            State {
                name: "off";
                PropertyChanges { target: rect; color: "red"; }
            }
        ]

        state: "on"
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `onPressed: ...` and `onReleased: ...` it is simpler to have the Timer `running: parent.pressed` - and it is more declarative.

Comment: @derM really, I haven't thought about that. It's much better. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @ArmanOganesyan and if I want to disable it, pressing again for 3 seconds and turn the color green? How do I do that?

Comment: @sebba23 I've edit my answer. In this case I suggest using states.

Comment: You can add a property `property bool on: true` to the Rectangle. Set it's color to `color: on ? "green" : "red"`. And `onTriggered: rect.on = !rect.on` - or use states as done by Arman O.